# Get List from Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I have a manipulate

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   Graphics3D[{Red, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h1}}, r1], 
   Green, Pyramid[{{r2, -r2, h1 + 0.01}, {-r2, -r2, h1 + 0.01}, {-r2, r2, 
        h1 + 0.01}, {r2, r2, h1 + 0.01}, {0, 0, h2 + h1}}]
     }, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 20}},
    Boxed -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
    ClipPlanes -> {i, j, 1, -k + 0.01}], 
   ContourPlot3D[
    i x + j y + z == k, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 20.01}, 
    Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3]]]}],
 "Cylinder",
 {{h1, 5, "H"}, 2, 10, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r1, 3, "R"}, 2, 5, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "", "Pyramid",
 {{h2, 5, "H"}, 2, 10, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r2, 3, "R"}, 2, 5, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "", "Plane",
 {{i, 0, "X"}, 0, 2, .01, ImageSize -> Small, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{j, 0, "Y"}, 0, 2, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 0, "Z"}, 0, 20, .01, ImageSize -> Small,   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

How can I get List of points (click by button), which now set in the Manipulate

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get"? Store it in a variable, print it?

Comment: @anderstood Store it in a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is to save the variables into a list. For example, change the first two lines to

```
Manipulate[saveState = {h1, r1, h2, r2, i, j, k}; Show[{...
```

now you can run the Manipulate, adjust the sliders. When done, go to a new cell and recall the positions of the slider-variables by examining the list

```
saveState
```

Comment: This works, thank you